# Display picture in React Native

Tags: image, react-native

I'm making a React Native app with Expo. In my app, I upload some pictures via the API of my website, in a local database (SQLite).
The problem is that I want to display these pictures like a gallery but I can't. I'm doing something like this:

```
for (var x =0; x <= prod.length; x++) {
    require('../../web/image/'+prod[x].picture);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In React and React Native, a component renders using its `render` function.

For instance, in React Native the [native Image component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) is used for rendering images.

To render a single image, your component should include something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        source={require('/react-native/img/favicon.png')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Adding logic inside of your [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) is easy too! Simply wrap any Javascript code inside of curly braces as follows:

```
renderImages() {
    var images = [];
    for (var x=0; x <= prod.length; x++){
        images.push(<Image key={x} source={require('../../web/image/'+prod[x].picture)}/>);
    }
    return images;
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      { this.renderImages(); }
    </View>
  );
}
```

*Note that I added a `key` property to each Image element. When rendering arrays, you must add keys. See the following document for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html*